# Extracting SOAP Headers through CXF in a camel-context.xml file

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, cxf, apache-camel

Alright, so I have a SOAP web service setup using Camel and Spring living on a Karaf server. When I receive a SOAP message, the way it's currently working is that the body is extracted and output to a file that is the processed via XSLT in another location.

The original SOAP message has a messageId in the header of the SOAP message, and I'd like to read that messageId and use it as the name of the file that is output to the location to be processed via XSLT. I'm pretty new to Camel and Spring so this is all foreign territory to me.

The dataFormat mode is PAYLOAD, so I figured the SOAP header would be available after going through the inInterceptor and I have been attempting to parse it in a camel:camelContext route to no avail.

The endpoint uses a wss4jInInterceptor if that's of any value.

Documentation on this seems to be sparse, and I'm just not sure where to go with it, any help would be appreciated!

This is what the endpoint looks like:

```
<camelcxf:cxfEndpoint id="ILDOCWebService" 
    address="INTERNAL URL"
    wsdlURL="/META-INF/wsdl/SIP/VNP_ServiceCore.wsdl"
    serviceName="s:VNP_Service"
    endpointName="s:VNPSOAPPort"
    xmlns:s="http://it.ojp.gov/VNExchange/1.0/ws">

    <camelcxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="wss4jInInterceptor"/>
        <ref bean="wsAddressingInterceptor"/>
    </camelcxf:inInterceptors>

    <camelcxf:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="wss4jOutInterceptor"/>
    </camelcxf:outInterceptors>

    <camelcxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD" />
        <entry key="publishedEndpointUrl" value="URL HIDDEN" />
    </camelcxf:properties>

</camelcxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

And the route looks like this:

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
    <camel:route id="ILDOCWS_NotifyingAgencyWS_File_From_NotifyingAgencyWSClient">
        <camel:from uri="cxf:bean:ILDOCWebService"/>
        <camel:setHeader headerName="msgId">
            <camel:xpath>s:Header/MessageId</camel:xpath><!--This is where I'm trying to get the messageId extracted -->
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:log loggingLevel="INFO" message="&gt;&gt;&gt;MessageID:  ${header.msgID}"/>
        <camel:convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
        <camel:log loggingLevel="INFO" message="&gt;&gt;&gt;BODY:    ${body}"/>
        <camel:multicast>
            <camel:pipeline>
                <camel:setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
                    <camel:simple>${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}_{{msgID}}.xml</camel:simple>
                </camel:setHeader>
                <camel:to uri="INTERNAL URL HIDDEN"/>
            </camel:pipeline>
            <camel:pipeline>
                <camel:to uri="xslt:/META-INF/responseMessage.xsl"/>
            </camel:pipeline>
        </camel:multicast>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Comment: The SOAP headers are supposed to be included in the Exchange, however,  operations after the cxf endpoint can replace the exchange In/Out Message objects, effectively discarding the original headers.

Comment: Please add a sample route definition that includes the type of operations you are currently doing between the source endpoint (`cxf:bean`) and the destination (where you expect the header to be present).